# COM marshalling gone wild

Tags: winapi, com, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have a really weird problem in a customer environment - I have an exe that calls 3 or 4 in-proc COM objects (dlls). These dlls also call each other and the main exe (through COM events).

This worked fine for a long time (5 years?) and continues to work fine on thousands of machines, but for one customer (Windows 2008 R2) the whole system goes haywire: the main exe creates a plain vanilla apartment threaded COM object (no custom marshalling) using CoCreateInstance and starts calling its methods.

Everything works fine for a few dozen or a hundred calls, but then something truly unexpected happens: a call to one of the in-proc COM objects (which is really a proxy returned by COM) gets marshalled to a separate thread created by COM. That method calls back to the main exe, but the call, yet again, gets marshalled to another thread. And the code on that thread starts accessing controls, and that is when really bad things start to happen - the main thread is blocked, and accessing controls created on the main thread from the secondary thread blocks too (SentMessage, GetPropW, etc.).

Has anybody seen this?

Is there any way to disable this behavior or get rid of COM marshalling completely (which is useless in this case since there are no threads created by my app)?

I replaced CoCreateInstance() with my own function that, given the class GUID, figures the executable path, loads it, calls DllgetClassObject and then calls IClassFactory::CreateObject. That works perfectly fine, all of my objects are now running on the main thread. But the out-of-proc objects (which my version of CoCreateInstance does not touch) start failing too with very similar errors: I create an instance of the Outlook.Application object, then create a new MailItem object. Accessing any property on that object now returns 
*'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread'*. It wasn't! I logged the thread id when the objects are created. All the calls are on the main thread!

Help! How do I stop this madness?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you double-check to make sure your calls to `CoInitialize/Ex()` match the DLL's actual threading model? If they match, then an in-proc COM object should not be using a marshaling proxy, and a call into such an object should definitely not be getting marshaled to another thread, let alone a COM-managed thread.

Comment: Is your special CoCreateInstance specific to your testings or does your app uses this from the beginning? That sounds strange, like you do your own stuff for half of it, and let COM do the rest for the other half (which could lead to wrong threading messages like you see).

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: yep, it all matches. Tis is a plain vanilla exe/dlls written in Delphi 7.

Comment: @Simon Mourier: I only added my own version of CoCreateInstance after I ran in to this problem.

Comment: Turned out the problem was caused by a separate dll (recently updated) that called CoInitialize and never checked the return value. It then unconditionally called CoUninitialize(). If CoInitialize failed (wrong apartment etc.), CoUninitialize() would kill the COM system that was successfully initialized before.